# How can I add dynamic item in iPhone if third party payment is not allowed?

Tags: ios

I need to understand one point. Apple has made it compulsory to use in App purchase for virtual items or goods and no third party payment solutions are accepted. But if the items are dynamically coming from a CMS into the iPhone, then we cannot use in App purchase since In-App purchases means data has to be entered one time.

Can anyone give me a solution of how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Most people handle this situation by creating some sort of virtual currency that can be consumed in the app to buy resources. For example, Magic Piano from Smule (along with other Smule apps) lets you buy "smoola" that can later be used to add songs and instruments to the app. New songs appear daily, and you don't need to purchase them through the app store; instead, you pick one out and pay for it with the smoola from your account. You can earn some smoola in certain ways (like watching a video), and you can buy packs of smoola using in-app purchase at prices ranging from $3 to $100.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map your dynamic items with a product id in iTunes. Create new iTunes products in advance for your dynamic items.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) the documentation. It's short but comprehensive. In my opinion , yes , you can set any price you want in the app as long as you don't point up to the fact that the user can buy the same thing for less from your website.